# Linq to SQL insert fails, nvarchar to bigint

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

We're trying to create a record with some binary data. I'm not sure if it's the binary data or something else.

Our table is defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[InstitutionEntityIPs](
[InstitutionEntityIPID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[InstitutionEntityID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[FromIP] [varchar](39) NULL,
[ToIP] [varchar](39) NULL,
[FromIPInteger] [bigint] NULL,
[ToIPInteger] [bigint] NULL,
[IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL,
[DateEntered] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_tempInstitutionEntityIPs_DateEntered]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
[RecordVersion] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
[FromIPBinary] [varbinary](16) NULL,
[ToIPBinary] [varbinary](16) NULL
```

Our C# code looks like this:

```
db.InstitutionEntityIPs.InsertOnSubmit(institutionEntityIp);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

And the SQL Profiler shows that the SQL trying to get executed is this:

```
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO [dbo].[InstitutionEntityIPs](
        [InstitutionEntityID], [FromIP], [ToIP], [FromIPInteger], [ToIPInteger], 
        [IsActive], [DateEntered], [FromIPBinary], [ToIPBinary])
    VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8)',
N'@p0 uniqueidentifier,@p1 varchar(8000),@p2 varchar(8000),
    @p3 bigint,@p4 bigint,@p5 bit,@p6 datetime,
    @p7 varbinary(max) ,@p8 varbinary(max) ',
@p0='06E82E96-CE8D-4D2A-B1F3-BD606C2BD021',
@p1='2001:db8:ac10:fe01::',
@p2='2001:db8:ac10:fe01::1:0',
@p3=0,
@p4=0,
@p5=1,
@p6='2015-05-28 12:41:35.873',
@p7=0x20010DB8AC10FE010000000000000000,
@p8=0x20010DB8AC10FE010000000000000000
```

SQL is saying: *Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint.*

I've tried doing a SQL insert with limited data, and still get the same message.

```
DECLARE @p0 uniqueidentifier,
    @p1 varchar(8000),
    @p2 varchar(8000),
    @p3 bigint,
    @p4 bigint,
    @p5 bit,
    @p6 datetime,
    @p7 varbinary(max) ,
    @p8 varbinary(max) 

SELECT @p0='06E82E96-CE8D-4D2A-B1F3-BD606C2BD021',
@p1=N'2001:db8:ac10:fe01::',
@p2=N'2001:db8:ac10:fe01::1:0',
@p3=0,
@p4=0,
@p5=1,
@p6='2015-05-28 12:41:35.873',
@p7=0x20010DB8AC10FE010000000000000000,
@p8=0x20010DB8AC10FE010000000000000000

INSERT INTO [dbo].[InstitutionEntityIPs](
        [InstitutionEntityID], [FromIP], [ToIP], 
        [IsActive])
    VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2,  
        @p5)
```

What is it seeing as nvarchar and trying to put into bigint?

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.InstitutionEntityIPs")]
public partial class InstitutionEntityIP : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);

    private int _InstitutionEntityIPID;

    private System.Guid _InstitutionEntityID;

    private string _FromIP;

    private string _ToIP;

    private System.Nullable<long> _FromIPInteger;

    private System.Nullable<long> _ToIPInteger;

    private bool _IsActive;

    private System.DateTime _DateEntered;

    private System.Data.Linq.Binary _RecordVersion;

    private System.Data.Linq.Binary _FromIPBinary;

    private System.Data.Linq.Binary _ToIPBinary;

    private EntityRef<InstitutionEntity> _InstitutionEntity;
```

Comment: What is `institutionEntityIp`? A custom DTO, or an instance of the mapped table entity (the class LINQ-to-SQL generated)?

Comment: It is the class LINQ-to-SQL generated in my DBML.

Comment: Can you include it's definition here?

Comment: Added it's private variables. Do you want more?

Comment: Are there triggers or computed columns or anything like that?

Comment: No, that by itself eliminates one possibility (that the table schema had changed since the DBML was generated).

Comment: JamesZ, you are a genius. Yes, there was a constraint that used an expression with a function. That was it. Thank you!!!